# Sed print digits from string

Tags: regex, unix, sed

Have next configuration file:

```
[DEFAULT]
SenderCompID=PB
ConnectionType=acceptor
SocketAcceptPort=4444
FileStorePath=store
FileLogPath=/apps/test
HttpAcceptPort=3333
TransportDataDictionary=../../share/quickfix/FIXT11.xml
AppDataDictionary.FIX.4.0=../../share/quickfix/FIX40.xml
AppDataDictionary.FIX.4.1=../../share/quickfix/FIX41.xml
AppDataDictionary.FIX.4.2=../../share/quickfix/FIX42.xml
AppDataDictionary.FIX.4.3=../../share/quickfix/FIX43.xml
AppDataDictionary.FIX.4.4=../../share/quickfix/FIX44.xml
AppDataDictionary.FIX.5.0=../../share/quickfix/FIX50.xml
AppDataDictionary.FIX.5.0SP1=../../share/quickfix/FIX50SP1.xml
AppDataDictionary.FIX.5.0SP2=../../share/quickfix/FIX50SP2.xml
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=23:59:59
StartDay=sun
EndDay=sat

[SESSION]
TargetCompID=TUDOR-TEST
BeginString=FIX.4.4
DataDictionary=../../share/quickfix/FIX44.xml

[SESSION]
TargetCompID=SECOR-TEST
BeginString=FIX.4.4
DataDictionary=../../share/quickfix/FIX44.xml
```

I want to print value of `SocketAcceptPort` tag by using sed, in my case it's `4444`.
I used this regexp but no luck: `sed 's/SocketAcceptPort=[0-9]+//g' file.cfg`
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through sed,

```
$ sed -n '/^SocketAcceptPort/s/.*=//p' file
4444
```

It searches for the line which starts with `SocketAcceptPort`, if it found any then it remove all the characters upto the `=` symbol. Finally the remaining characters got printed. In our case it's `4444`

Comment: Thanks, it works! Could you please explain how it works. We change everything in string before equals on digit (s/.*=//p)?

Comment: I like this better than the one using back reference, since its simpler to understand. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `awk` if you like to try:

```
awk -F= '/SocketAcceptPort/ {print $2}' file 
4444
```

Comment: Thanks, should use sed.

Comment: @Iurii You are free to select what you need.  Its just a suggestion, that should work. Its easy logic too. Split the line by `=`, search for `SocketAcceptPort` and print second field. As far as I have seen, if you have `sed` you have `awk` :)

Answer (score 0):

Another `sed`,

```
sed -n 's/^SocketAcceptPort=\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p' yourfile
```

If you have `-E` option in `sed`,

```
sed -En 's/^SocketAcceptPort=([0-9]+).*/\1/p' yourfile
```